# Can I pass user credentials across google app engine apps?

Tags: authentication, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, credentials

I have a web app hosted on google app engine and want to do two things at the same time: 1. Add a second app (it would be separate in that it would be accessed through another domain or subdomain and it could be a second service on the same application or a new default service on a second application, depending on whether either of those is impacted by the answer to the question below) 2. Create a login for users. The piece of this that I'm not familiar with and want to address up-front is whether/how I can make it so that if a user logs into one of the websites and hits a link to the other website, they don't need to login again.

The ideal solution would be something that google supports, but I couldn't find any solutions (google supported or not), so other solutions are fine if that doesn't exist.

Comment: You can assign cookies to a domain and allow subdomains to use the same cookies.  That is an easy way to allow single sign on for more than one app.